# How to make a summary list of one column in a large CSV file?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have 20,000 rows in a CSV which I have loaded using d3. Within this CSV there are roughly 4,000 unique category names (each being repeated across various numbers of rows).

I would like to make a list (an array or objects) of all the ~4,000 category names from my CSV, to be able to filter out categories that I do not want to work with.

See code and data sample below; the category column is called `feature_id`.

[image]

```
var rowConverter = function(d){
    return{
        event_date: parseTime(d.event_date),
        claim_number: d.claim_number,
        cause: d.cause,
        detail_cause: d.detail_cause,
        paid_total: parseFloat(d.paid_total),
        feature_id: d.feature_id,
        id: parseFloat(d.id)
    };
}


d3.csv('claims_cwy.csv', rowConverter, function(dataset) {
    console.log(dataset);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [d3.nest](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) examples. And [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#nest) are the docs for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty array, iterate over this dataset and for each iteration check this category if it exists. If not, add to the array. Something like:

```
const categories = []
dataset.forEach( item => {
  if ( categories.indexOf(item.category) <= 0)
    categories.push(item.category)
})
```

PS: I don't know which of this attributes in the row represents the category, it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, could you clarify where i substitute in my feature_id? I guess it would be for what you call 'item' or 'category'.... Probably basic questions, sorry I am quite beginner!

The categories all correspond to dates, which are not pictured above(the table is huge)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve what you want. If you want to keep it D3-*ish* you could make use of [`d3.set()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#set) which not only guarantees uniqueness of its values, but also allows you to provide an accessor to extract the categories' values, i.e. the field `feature_id`, from your data.

```
const categories = d3.set(dataset, d => d.feature_id);
```

Note, however, that this requires an additional loop through your data. As you claim to have a large set of data, you might want to do it step by step by [adding](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#set_add) to the set in the row converter function.

```
const categories = d3.set();
const rowConverter = function(d) {
  categories.add(d.feature_id);
};
```

Whatever approach you prefer the unique category values are available by calling [`d3.values()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#set_values).